# AWSDynamoDB - empty task result

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

```
task = [[task continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task)
{       
      NSLog(@"%@: Get profile for identity : %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), cognitoUID);  
      AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper *dynamoDBObjectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper];
      return [dynamoDBObjectMapper load:[TPLCognitoUserDBO class] hashKey:cognitoUID rangeKey:nil];

         }]continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task)
        {
            if (task.error) {
                NSLog(@"%@: The request failed. Error: [%@]",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), task.error);
            }
            if (task.exception) {
                NSLog(@"%@: The request failed. Exception: [%@]", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), task.exception);
            }
            if (task.result) {

                TPLCognitoUserDBO *cognitoProfile = task.result;

                if(cognitoProfile)
                {
                    NSLog(@"%@: User ID %@ ::",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [cognitoProfile TPLHandle]);
                    [userIDFound setString: [cognitoProfile TPLHandle]];

                } else {
                    NSLog(@"%@: Output has no records in it.", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
                }

            }

        return nil;

        }];

return task;
```

Gives me error

> 2015-08-24 22:41:21.539 myplan[9904:815677] -[AWSTask TPLHandle]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>
> 2015-08-24 22:41:21.905 myplan[9904:815766] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Debug]
>   AWSSignature.m line:320 | -[AWSSignatureV4Signer signRequestV4:] |
>   payload {"Key":{"TPLCognitoID":{"S":"some value
>   here"}},"TableName":"TPLCognitoUser"}
>
> 2015-08-24 22:41:22.341 myplan[9904:815766] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Verbose]
>   AWSURLResponseSerialization.m line:79 | -[AWSJSONResponseSerializer
>   responseObjectForResponse:originalRequest:currentRequest:data:error:]
>   | Response body: [{}]

** DB Definition

```
@interface TPLCognitoUserDBO :  AWSDynamoDBObjectModel <AWSDynamoDBModeling>

//Keys

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *TPLCognitoID;

//Other Attributes

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *TPLHandle;
```

Comment: Seems that `task.result` is a `AWSTask` object and not a `TPLCognitoUserDBO` one.

Comment: @Larme : dynamoDBObjectMapper load:[TPLCognitoUserDBO class] - This should ensure the object returned is of type TPLCognitoUserDBO?

Comment: NSLog on task.result gives me this

Task Result <AWSTask: 0x7fcfd1518ad0; completed = NO; cancelled = NO; faulted = NO;>

Comment: the test result shown a  <AWSTask> type, but your code is continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task). the task type is not matched in your code.

Comment: Thank You @YiZhu ... Changing to AWSTask worked. I wrote this piece after the aws sdk upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the test result shown a type, but your code is continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task). the task type is not matched in your code. – Yi Zhu